# greenline when rendering video on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, video, stream

I am rendering a video stream on a canvas, sometime a greenline appears on the side of the rendered video, why ? and how to fix this ?

It happens when the canvas size is smaller than the video resolution!!

The Code is very simple

```
    let videoConstraints: MediaTrackConstraints;
    if (options) {
      if (!CameraResolutions[options.resolution]) options.resolution = CameraQuality.Auto;
      videoConstraints = {
        deviceId: options.deviceId,
        frameRate: { ideal: 30 },
        // facingMode: options.facingMode,
        width: { ideal: CameraResolutions[options.resolution][0] }, // 720
        height: { ideal: CameraResolutions[options.resolution][1] }, // 720
      };
    }
    const constraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {
      video: videoConstraints ?? true,
      audio: false,
    };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(options.constraints);
...
this.ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
```

`this.video` is a `MediaStream` received from a webcam.

I am testing on chrome

UPDATE : Based on [coralee's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17531641/coralee) comment updated to this and it worked :) Most of the time :( But I need a better solution

```
      const w = this.canvas.width - 10;
      const h = this.canvas.height - 10;
      const x = 5; // to center the video on canvas
      const y = 5;
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.video, x, y, w, h);
```

UPDATE 2 : The real problem : Our WebRTC SDK is enabling simulcast and its using vp8 codec https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP8 and therefore the canvas size should be dividable by 4, 8 or 16
The Solution : `Math.round(Math.min(videoWidth, maxSize) / 16) * 16;`

Comment: Please share an [MCVE], where we can see exactly which options are passed in every steps.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the file format.

I used to be a video editor and I remember this being a [common problem](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro-discussions/green-line-on-the-right-side-after-export/m-p/9246297) with video exports.

The best way to fix it was to scale the video up a pixel. So if your video was 100%, you make it 101%.

Comment: Its a `MediaStream` from the webcam

Comment: Can't change the video itself just the container its being rendered on

Comment: It seemed to work :) tanks

Comment: Please [edit] this answer so that it looks like an answer. Don't abuse the answer box to post comments. Just be affirmative and propose your solution, if you wish with a disclaimer that it may not fit perfectly OP's situation.